# Django POST method error

Tags: python, django, server, django-rest-framework, python-requests

I have some mistake error with my Django Project.

So, i'm use Django Rest Framework

```
class CompaniesInviteView(APIView):

    def get(self, request, pk=None):
        return Response({}, status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

    def post(self, request, pk=None, **kwargs):
        print request.POST
```

Urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include

from views import *

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/invite/?$', CompaniesInviteView.as_view(), name='companies'),

)
```

And, when i'm send POST request:

```
import requests

r = requests.Session()

data = {
    "users": [
        {
          "first_name": "1",
          "last_name": "1",
          "email": "123@12.eu",
          "password1": "123",
          "password2": "123"
        },
        {
          "first_name": "12",
          "last_name": "12",
          "email": "1234@12.eu",
          "password1": "123",
          "password2": "123" }
    ]
}
print data
reg = r.post('http://localhost:8000/api/companies/15/invite', data=data)
```

Django say me:

```
<QueryDict: {u'users': [u'password1', u'first_name', u'last_name', u'email', u'password2', u'password1', u'first_name', u'last_name', u'email', u'password2']}>
2015-12-08 18:09:31,393 DEBUG fus.utils params (101) GET: <QueryDict: {}>
2015-12-08 18:09:31,393 DEBUG fus.utils params (102) POST: <QueryDict: {u'users': [u'password1', u'first_name', u'last_name', u'email', u'password2', u'password1', u'first_name', u'last_name', u'email', u'password2']}>
```

So i'm send

```
{
        "users": [
            {
              "first_name": "1",
              "last_name": "1",
              "email": "123@12.eu",
              "password1": "123",
              "password2": "123"
            },
            {
              "first_name": "12",
              "last_name": "12",
              "email": "1234@12.eu",
              "password1": "123",
              "password2": "123" }
        ]
    }
```

I'm get

```
{u'users': [u'password1', u'first_name', u'last_name', u'email', u'password2', u'password1', u'first_name', u'last_name', u'email', u'password2']}
```

And, i don't know why.
Can someone help me? Maybe someone know, how fix this

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: I'm want get first dict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In requests you need to use `json` instead of `data` like:

```
reg = r.post('http://localhost:8000/api/companies/15/invite', json=data)
```

and to access the post data you should use `request.data`

```
class CompaniesInviteView(APIView):

    def get(self, request, pk=None):
        return Response({}, status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

    def post(self, request, pk=None, **kwargs):
        print request.data
```